# Magento 1.9 - Custom options different for each product

Tags: custom-options

I have a Race-Registration virtual product with 12 custom options (First name, Last name, Dob etc..). Everything works fine exept when I add 2 or more of the products to the cart: in this case Custom options are the same for every product. I would like magento to ask me different data for single product added to the cart.

Already tried Configurable and Bundle products without success

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is something the product model does not provide.

Use a booking extension (there'll be something at google)

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I had a look, but I don't need a special booking module, in my use case the event date is fixed. I just need to register every participant data by using custom options. The example problem is: if a cycling team wants to buy 5 "tickets" for the race the system ask for custom-options once and not for every participant. Thanks Again